# How can I mock GoogleCredential in order to test my business logic

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, google-api-java-client

I am writing a unit test for one of my application and part of that requires mocking out the GoogleCredential object of the google-api-java-client. We use service accounts to authenticate between services in our SOA. I would like to do something like:

```
GoogleCredential cred = mock(GoogleCredential.class);
when(cred.refreshToken()).thenReturn(true);
```

But I get an error during the "when" call indicating that the "lock" instance inside of the GoogleCredential object is null. Is there some way to get Mockito to successfully stub the method call?

Comment: Do you expect being able to access real Google servers with a mocked credential or are you running local (mocked) tests servers?

Comment: I do not expect to access real credentials from the test. I only expect to test the code I have around the calls to the "refreshToken" method. I do not expect ANY of the logic inside of GoogleCredential to be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I had not realized that the method in question was "final", so I had to use PowerMockito to stub the final method. So, since I am using TestNG, I modified the class signature to "extends PowerMockTestCase" and added the class annotation "@PrepareForTest(GoogleCredential.class)"... Finally, in the test method:

```
PowerMockito.stub(credentials.getClass().getMethod("refreshToken")).toReturn(true);
```

Those changes allowed the method to be mocked/stubbed for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, seven years later you can check out MockGoogleCredential, made just for that purpose.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).